# React Native Expo Web not Updating

Tags: react-native, expo

I got a problem with my react native app:
i start the app with
`npx expo start -w`
so it opens in the browser. It normally opens the app with the latest changes. When i make some changes and save the file in the app/screen the app will reload. But when i do more changes and save after that the console it says
`web compiled successfully`
but the app itself in the browser doesnt change at all and it stays like that even after reloading the page/app.
Any suggestions whats the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You might have two issues. If you're not seeing automatic updates when you save the file, it is likely because Fast Refresh isn't automatically enabled with web. I had same issue, and found that some templates from expo were allowing for Fast Refresh on web, while others didn't. It led me to see that those templates with FR had `expo-router` installed in `node_modules`, and the entry point for the application was in `node_modules/expo-router/entry.js`. `expo-router` states:

```js
// `@expo/metro-runtime` MUST be the first import to ensure Fast Refresh works
// on web.
import '@expo/metro-runtime';

import { App } from 'expo-router/build/qualified-entry';
import { renderRootComponent } from 'expo-router/build/renderRootComponent';

// This file should only import and register the root. No components or exports
// should be added here.
renderRootComponent(App);
```

so if you `npm install --save-dev @expo/metro-runtime` (or `yarn` if you use that) and then import it at the very beginning of your entry point in the app (it should state where that is in the command line when you save and web gets bundled) Fast Refresh should then work. [H/t to palicko on github](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/23104#issuecomment-1689566248) for confirming and providing steps.

As for why you're not seeing updates after you hard refresh in the browser, that may be a different issue. Hopefully you figured it out by now!